# leveling system with discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

So, I want to make a leveling/xp system for my discord bot (like mee6 or tatsumaki) but the only way I know how to do this is by using mSQL. Is there a way to do this just using discord.js or is there an eazier way to do this?

*I'm sorry for this question being so general but i can't find an answer anywhere, thanks*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could, though using a DB will help more in the future.

Using a Database will probably be the only solution unless you want to write files uselessly or want the levels to be cleared upon restart. From my experience, a database will just work best if you want to store *anything* like this. Also when using a Database you can use other tables to save more information (Command statistics, etc.) without a problem.

I've been there myself, though once you get over not wanting to use a database and setting one up you'll wonder how you lived without it.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into creating a database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a point system on my bot. I'm saving it on a JSON file, it's pretty easy to do with node.

You can scan all the users every time you launch the bot for new users and initialize them in your file.

The downside is that you can erase all of the file if you parse it when you boot the bot and you get an error.

I'm considering switching to a DB instead.